# Magento 1.4 catalog_eav_attribute - Added Custom Column But Values Not Saving

Tags: php, magento, module, entity-attribute-value

I developed a custom module for Magento 1.8 where it works exactly as I want and I am now retrofitting it to Magento 1.4.

In the catalog_product_attribute/edit tab, I used an observer to add a field to the form so that folks can choose from an additional option when creating or updating an attribute. In my install script, column `is_grouped_product_filter` is added to `catalog_eav_attribute` table and it is indeed there.

Just as I did in 1.8, here in 1.4 I went to `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController` and to the `saveAction()` to make sure that my new field was being included in the data array for saving to the database, and indeed it is.

It simply will not save the value to my custom column in 1.4. However, between the 1.4 - 1.8 versions that I am working on, it appears that the saveAction() is identical.

I also tried manually adding my data in the save action just to see if it does anything and it does not. I added my data to the data array manually with this:

```
$data['is_grouped_product_filter'] = 1;
```

Is there some extra step I am missing in 1.4 to allow me to save a value to the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just after posting this question, I found the answer here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10565/cant-save-custom-data-to-sales-order-table

> Try clearing the cache. Even if your cache is disabled the table
>   describe results are still cached by ZF.

I then went and did exactly that and it worked like a champ.

Comment: AAAAHHHHHHH MAAAAGENNNNNTTTOOOOOOOOOOO! (!!!!111) Thanks for sharing this answer @Shawn.

Answer (score -1):

Clearing the `/var/cache` folder fixes the issue